# How to view installed Java documentation?

Tags: apt, java, documentation

I installed the `openjdk-11-doc` package but I can't find an easy way to access it. Using `dpkg -L` I can see that it's installed in `/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index.html` but there must be a way of browsing the documents that doesn't involve exploring the file system.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid file-browsing, is to make a bookmark in your browser to:

```
file:///usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index.html
```

Then you don't have to explore through the filemanager.  Of course you could make it a link on your Desktop so you'd **just double-click the Desktop icon**.